# IBM Worklight - Android "Downloading Application update" dialog disappears if tapping outside of the dialog

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

After Building and deploying the app in Worklight and testing the Direct Update feature, the  application update dialog appears and when clicking OK, another dialog window appears with the   update progress bar.

At this time, if I will tap outside of the update dialog, the dialog gets cancelled and the progress window disappears. So to update the app I need to kill and reopen the app. This is not happening in iOS.

How to disable the outside tap events with application update in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the update process continues even if you tap outside of the progress bar dialog and dismiss it. But in any case, this is indeed an unwelcome scenario.

This is a known defect that was fixed in a subsequent iFix release for the 5.0.6.2, 6.0.0.2 and 6.1.0.1 fix packs releases.

- If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can get the latest ifix for your version/edition from [Fixcentral](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).
- Otherwise, you can download the latest Developer Edition (non-customer) of the 6.1.0.1 ifix from Eclipse Marketplace. Or download a zip file of the latest [5.0.6.2](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip) or [6.0.0.2](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip).

Comment: @Kavin, once verified fixed, please mark as Answered.